# export products prestashop 1.7.2.4 to xml using php script

Tags: php, xml, dom, mysqli, export

I'm working on a php script to export all products from prestashop 1.7.4.2 to xml. 
The script is running for minutes & returns in a 404 error. No errors showing up...

The sql query is working fine thanks to Nick in my [previous post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50446428/product-export-to-xml-using-sql-queries?noredirect=1#comment87912296_50446428)

How would I get this 404 error solved? 
I'm running on apache, working with php 7.0, the script needs to prepare an export of +- 4500 products.

This is the script:

```
//error_reporting
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

//ini_set
ini_set('max_execution_time' ,0);
ini_set('set_memory_limit', -1);

// Create connection
$dbconnect = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($dbconnect->connect_error)
{
    die('Connection failed: ' . $dbconnect->connect_error);
}
$query = 'SELECT
    psc5_product.id_product AS \'product_id\',
    psc5_product.ean13 AS \'ean13\',
    psc5_product.price AS \'price\',
    psc5_product.reference AS \'product_reference\',
    psc5_stock_available.quantity AS \'available_stock\',
    psc5_manufacturer.name AS \'brand\',
    psc5_product_lang.description AS \'description\',
    psc5_product_lang.name AS \'title\',
    concat("https://www.natureldeluxe.be/", psc5_category_lang.link_rewrite, "/", psc5_product_lang.link_rewrite) AS \'deeplink\',
    concat("https://www.natureldeluxe.be/", psc5_image.id_image, "-large_default/", psc5_product_lang.link_rewrite, ".jpg") AS \'imagelink\' 
FROM
    psc5_product 
    INNER JOIN
        psc5_stock_available 
        ON psc5_stock_available.id_product = psc5_product.id_product 
    INNER JOIN
        psc5_manufacturer 
        ON psc5_manufacturer.id_manufacturer = psc5_product.id_manufacturer 
    INNER JOIN
        psc5_product_lang 
        ON psc5_product_lang.id_product = psc5_product.id_product 
    INNER JOIN
        psc5_category_lang 
        ON psc5_category_lang.id_category = psc5_product.id_category_default 
    INNER JOIN
        psc5_image 
        ON psc5_image.id_product = psc5_product.id_product';
$dbresult = mysqli_query($dbconnect, $query);
// create a new XML document
$doc = new DomDocument('1.0');
// create root node
$root = $doc->createElement('root');
$root = $doc->appendChild($root);
// process one row at a time
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($dbresult))
{
    // add a child node for each field
    foreach ($row as $product_id => $product_id)
    {
        foreach ($row as $ean13 => $ean13)
        {
            foreach ($row as $price => $price)
            {
                foreach ($row as $ean13 => $ean13)
                {
                    foreach ($row as $product_reference => $product_reference)
                    {
                        foreach ($row as $available_stock => $available_stock)
                        {
                            foreach ($row as $brand => $brand)
                            {
                                foreach ($row as $description => $description)
                                {
                                    foreach ($row as $title => $title)
                                    {
                                        foreach ($row as $deeplink => $deeplink)
                                        {
                                            foreach ($row as $imagelink => $imagelink)
                                            {
                                            }
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
// while
// get completed xml document
$xml_string = $doc->saveXML();
echo $xml_string;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if this is your problem, especially it shouldn't cause a 404 error.  But the way your creating your XML doesn't look correct.

This should export the XML file with the column names from your SQL, each row under an `<product>` element...

```
$doc = new DomDocument('1.0');
// create root node
$root = $doc->createElement('root');
$root = $doc->appendChild($root);
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($dbresult)) {
    $newRow = $doc->createElement('product');
    foreach ( $row as $name=>$value )    {
        $element = $doc->createElement($name, $value);
        $newRow->appendChild($element);
    }
    $root->appendChild($newRow);
}
$xml_string = $doc->saveXML();
header('Content-type: application/xml');
echo $xml_string;
```

I'm happy to delete this answer if it's not relevant to the problem, but hopefully it may be of some help.

Comment: Yes, now the output works, but without the xml tags.... I see all product coming up... But just as a string. I would like to have the xml tags ... It needs to be a xml like this: 

<root>
<products>
<product_id>number</product_id>
<ean13>number</ean13>

Comment: Yes, now the output works, but without the xml tags.... 
Just changed this in your code: $element = $doc->createElement($name, htmlspecialchars($value)); I see all product coming up... But just as a string. I would like to have the xml tags ... It needs to be a xml like this: 

<root>
<product>
<product_id>number</product_id>
<ean13>number</ean13>
<price>number</price>
<reference>text</reference>
etc... 
</product>
<product>
etc....
</product>
</root>

Comment: I've added the line `header('Content-type: application/xml');` to flag that the output is XML to the browser.

Answer (score 0):

The export works fine on prestashop 1.7.4.2

Simple product export to xml using php & sql.

I will add the full modified code, so in case anyone need it:

```html
//error_reporting
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

//ini_set
ini_set('max_execution_time', 0);
ini_set('set_memory_limit', -1);

// Create connection
$dbconnect = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($dbconnect->connect_error) {
    die('Connection failed: ' . $dbconnect->connect_error);
}
$query    = 'SELECT
    psc5_product.id_product AS \'product_id\',
    psc5_product.ean13 AS \'ean13\',
    psc5_product.price AS \'price\',
    psc5_product.reference AS \'product_reference\',
    psc5_stock_available.quantity AS \'available_stock\',
    psc5_manufacturer.name AS \'brand\',
    psc5_product_lang.description AS \'description\',
    psc5_product_lang.name AS \'title\',
    concat("https://www.natureldeluxe.be/", psc5_category_lang.link_rewrite, "/", psc5_product_lang.link_rewrite) AS \'deeplink\',
    concat("https://www.natureldeluxe.be/", psc5_image.id_image, "-large_default/", psc5_product_lang.link_rewrite, ".jpg") AS \'imagelink\' 
FROM
    psc5_product 
    INNER JOIN
        psc5_stock_available 
        ON psc5_stock_available.id_product = psc5_product.id_product 
    INNER JOIN
        psc5_manufacturer 
        ON psc5_manufacturer.id_manufacturer = psc5_product.id_manufacturer 
    INNER JOIN
        psc5_product_lang 
        ON psc5_product_lang.id_product = psc5_product.id_product 
    INNER JOIN
        psc5_category_lang 
        ON psc5_category_lang.id_category = psc5_product.id_category_default 
    INNER JOIN
        psc5_image 
        ON psc5_image.id_product = psc5_product.id_product';
$dbresult = mysqli_query($dbconnect, $query);
// create a new XML document
$doc = new DomDocument('1.0');
// create root node
$root = $doc->createElement('root');
$root = $doc->appendChild($root);
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($dbresult)) {
    $newRow = $doc->createElement('product');
    foreach ( $row as $name=>$value )    {
        $element = $doc->createElement($name, htmlspecialchars($value));
        $newRow->appendChild($element);
    }
    $root->appendChild($newRow);
}
$xml_string = $doc->saveXML();
header('Content-type: application/xml');
echo $xml_string;
```